# logstash - add new field under array of json objects

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a JSON input as given below

```
{ 
"id":4,
"locale":"en"
"restaurants": [ 
    { "addressLine" : "123 Road Dr", "city" : "City ST", "phone" : "555-555-5555", "distance" : "0" } , 
    { "addressLine" : "456 Fake St", "city" : "City ST", "phone" : "555-123-1212", "distance" : "0" } 
] }
```

Here is want to add a new field called "fulladdress" under each object in "restaurant" array which holds the concatenated value of "addressLine" and "City".

I tried mutate,ruby filters but looks like I am missing something.

Please help

Comment: Please show us your Logstash config and how you tried to do it